# Reinstalling Lion on a Wiped Disk

Tags: macos, recovery, data-recovery

I have MacBook that was running Lion.

On a journey into finding the perfect operating system for me, I installed Arch Linux. Whilst doing this I wiped the disk (`/dev/sda1`) and created some Linux partitions.

Now, for reasons beyond my control, I'm in need of some Mac OS capabilities.

Yet, I have no idea on how to reinstall Lion. (I wiped the recovery disk, so it doesn't show up when holding <kbd>option</kbd> whilst booting, but luckily <kbd>option</kbd>-booting does still work). Is there anywhere I can get a bootable ISO (preferably free), from which Lion can be installed (through the App Store perhaps?). I have an old Snow Leopard disk laying around but it won't boot because of hardware incompatabilities (CPU isn't working).

Or, am I left no choice but buying a bootable Lion USB stick? PS: no bashing on Lion here from me. I like Lion, I like Mac. I just dislike the GNU tools available are always slightly different from their Linux counterparts, making cooperation with my Linux-loving peers a nightmare.

PPS: I would consider doing something "dark" to get everything working again. Also, I wouldn't mind losing my Arch partition, since I can always get it back from a backup.

#### edit

The machine I'm talking about is a 13" macbook pro 8,2.

The only tool I have is another macbook pro, an older one, that ran OS X snow leopard, but is updated to Lion recently. (aha, this can serve my purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1161069/make_a_bootable_lion_installer.html) will walk you through creating a bootable lion disk - although in order to 'purchase' you'd need to have access to a mac. Hope that helps (and good luck!)

Answer (score 1):

What model Mac do you have? That will limit the recovery options. Internet recovery or putting your Mac into target mode and connecting it to another Mac to run the installer are two good places to start.

Also, you can install Lion onto any old USB drive and then bring that to your Mac to boot up and fix things. Remember you only need a Mac that runs 10.6.8 to get at Lion from the app store. As long as you have an Internet connection, you can download the lion installer and run it to install over your Mac. Assuming it has a FireWire port, you can run the install in target disk mode. If not, you'll need to install to an external USB drive then take that drive to your Mac to boot things up.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect the info you were asking. I don't think internet recovery is present yet on my model. I'm trying to build a bootable usb as we speak.